# JQuery enable only button with value of True

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ejs

I got the following HTML code:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary jumbotron-td-enable-button enb btnEnable" value="<%= enables[i]%>">
  Enable
</button>
```

This button is rendered by dynamically pulling data on json file hence i got the following value `value="<%= enables[i] %>`

Here is my javascript:

```
$(".btnEnable").each(function() {
    var isEnable = $(this).val();
    if (isEnable == 'FALSE') {
        $(".enb").attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

My problem is that it does it all of the button, for example the value of the button is like this:

```
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
```

So i only want the FALSE button to be disabled. I did try to use ID and it does what i want but the problem is that it is only getting the first FALSE value and not the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `$('.enb')` will select all of the buttons. Instead you should use the `this` keyword within the `each()` call to reference the current button in the iteration. Try this:

```
$(".btnEnable").each(function() {
    var isEnable = $(this).val();
    $(this).prop("disabled", isEnable == 'FALSE');
});
```

Note the use of `prop()` here, as you can supply a boolean value to it which will work for either state of `isEnable`, meaning you can remove the `if` condition.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there - you got the value of the current button using

```
$(this).val();
```

The important factor there is "this". It refers to the element which is the subject of the current iteration of the .each loop.

So to change the disabled property of only the current button, the same principle applies:

```
$(".enb").attr("disabled", true);
```

should become

```
$(this).attr("disabled", true);
```

Using the .enb selector, will, as you noticed, disable all buttons which have the class "enb".

To refine it further, the jQuery documentation suggests you use `.prop()` rather than `.attr()` to set properties of this kind (assuming your jQuery version is >=1.6)

```
$(this).prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `.enb` with `$(this)`

`.enb` will select all elements matching. `$(this)` will select only current one in the loop.

```
$(".btnEnable").each(function() {
    var isEnable = $(this).val();
    if (isEnable == 'FALSE') {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        //$(this).prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```